# Why do solids cool when put in a vacuum chamber?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, vacuum, phase-transition

I was watching this video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6XrAtp9WvM&feature=youtu.be&t=6m31s) where some snow was put in a vacuum chamber, and it cooled down a fair bit after depressurizing. Why is this? I understand that a gas would cool down because it gets more spread out so there are fewer collisions between molecules and fewer molecules containing heat, but why would a solid such as snow cool down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solid to vapour transition (sublimation) when the pressure above the ice is low.
This transition requires energy (specific latent heat of sublimation - $2.8 \, \rm MJ \, kg^{-1}$)  and that energy comes from the ice itself and so the temperature of the ice drops.

You may have noticed that even though the temperature is below the freezing the amount is snow on the ground decreases with time if the air is dry.
Again this is an example of the sublimation of frozen water.
Given favourable condition of dry air (and a breeze) a wet shirt on a washing line when the air temperature is below the freezing point of water will first develop ice on its surface and then eventually the ice will sublime leaving a dry shirt.

**Update**

@DavidHammen has mentioned [freezer burn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezer_burn) which is an excellent example.

Comment: A couple more examples of sublimation: Crumbly old  ice cubes and freezer burnt meat in a freezer.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thank you. The dehydration of food in a freezer is an excellent example.